# Showing data in a UITableView added as a subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I´m trying to display a UITableView as a subview of a UIView.

When I trigger the action below, the view is shown but contain no data.

```
- (IBAction)youwin
{     
    UITableView *HSView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,200,500,600)] ;
    [self.view addSubview:HSView];
}
```

It looks like the code in the HSView.m file is not triggerd.

The `HSView.h` is imported into the main controller.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few problems in your code are :–

1. You are leaking memory as the memory management calls are not balanced. You will need to release the instance you've created after adding it as a subview.
2. When creating an instance of `UITableView`, you need to set the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties for the it to work properly. `dataSource` object is the one that provides the content and without it you will get an empty table view.
3. You are mentioning `HSView.h` so I am thinking `HSView` is a class. In that case `UITableView *HSView` is incorrect. If you wanted to instantiate `HSView` then do `HSView * hsView = ...`. If it is a subclass of `UITableView`, point 2 will hold for it too.

Comment: Hi and thank you for a better answer than my question  ;-)

Yes you are right, the HSView is a seperate class, so I changed it to:

`    HSView * hsView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,200,500,600)] ;
    [self.view addSubview:hsView];
    [hsView reloadData];`
 
But do I need to add this aswell? If I do the application fails...   
`    [hsView setDelegate:self];
    [hsView setDataSource:self];

`
I know I have to release it as well.

I must apologize for my elementary questions...

Comment: First of all it should be `HSView * hsView = [[HSView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 500, 600) style:UITableViewStylePlain];` and you will need to set a delegate and a data source for `HSView` object to show data.

Comment: Another thing is that `self`'s class should adopt `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols and implement the required methods that is needed to fill the data.

Comment: Thanks for all the good suggestions. But after hours of googling for samples, and testing different approaches, I´m still stuck. I´m struggling with the basic understanding of the link between the main view and the tableview with its datasource. I think I need a basic sample app that is using a UIView and adding a UITableView to show a list as a result of an event. Any suggestions where to look is appreciated. My goal is to add a high score list for a game i already have in the AppStore.